# combine multiple WHERE in single query with LIMIT 2 each

Tags: mysql

I have column like below

```
name              |     cat
----------------------------------------
ala               |     games
alaa              |     software
aha               |     games
asd               |     games
aad               |     software
aas               |     software
asd               |     books
aad               |     software
aas               |     books
```

So i have three query like below

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND cat='games' LIMIT 2 
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND cat='software' LIMIT 2
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND cat='books' LIMIT 2
```

So i want get first `2 result from each category` (games,books,software) ...Right now i use these three queries..how to combine them into ONE QUERY..

P.s This is just example..I am working with upto 10 categories ..I want something which dont waste much resource

Comment: DO you have primary key ? and how you decide which one is first value ? Also why you need full text search ? If you need 2 records per group it could be done is a better way.

Comment: yea i have primary key..and this is just example..i have more than million records where i use full text..

Comment: I have created an example to get the top n per group http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81395/16 , I am not quite sure if full text search could be implemented in there.

Comment: wats that :o sable answer "UNION" is working fine...thanks anyways

Comment: what if you have 100 category and you want first 2 data against each item.. are you doing to do 100 unions ?

Comment: ok please explain this in answer...I am new and all this t1 t2 confused me..

Comment: t1 and t2 are just the table alias, since the table name is used in outer as well as inside the where so to distinguish the alias is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these queries work, use `UNION`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(`name`) 
   AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 2 WHERE cat='games'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(`name`) 
   AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 2 WHERE cat='books'
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH(`name`) 
   AGAINST ('a*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 2 WHERE cat='software'
```

Regarding optimization, the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html) states "When combining LIMIT row_count with DISTINCT, MySQL stops as soon as it finds row_count unique rows."  So you should add this to limit the resources of the individual queries.

Comment: The computer has to do the work anyway; MySQL will be more efficient at this than post process (such as with PHP).  Ultimately, the `LIMIT 2` makes this difficult to do other ways, such as with `GROUP BY`.  You should check the query time to see if how long it takes the query to process.